# Posição scroll - JQUery - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Estou com dificuldade para fazer um script no qual eu tenho a seguinte estrutura

Onde o header e o footer são fixos e o main possui um scroll com o conteúdo. Eu gostaria de saber como pegar a posição do scroll do main?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Indexe o método [`scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) dentro do seu elemento `#main`. Ele retornará a posição vertical. Você pode indexar o [`scrollLeft`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/) caso querer a posição horizontal.

```
var $main = $('#main');
$main.scrollTop();
```

(eu espero que você esteja falando do scroll nativo)